# Names of ALU pins/anchors in circuitikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

In the TikZ diagram below I want to draw red arrows aligned with ALU pins as indicated in the 2nd figure. How do I do it?  The code used to generate the first picture is pasted below the 2nd figure.

The main obstacle of course is knowing what the ALU pins/anchors are called. Note that I have used the 1 bit adder (from the muxdemuxes class given on [Page 174 of the manual](https://texdoc.org/serve/circuitikz/0)) to represent the ALU. I can't seem to locate the pin/anchor names in the Circuitikz manual.

[image]

I want this,
[image: I want this]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{flowchart}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary {matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz} 
  
  \node[draw, black, thick,
  minimum width =5cm ,
  minimum height=5cm, , fill=teal!15] (regbox) at (9,0) {};

  \node[black,scale=1.0] at (9,2.2) {\textsf{REGISTER SET}};

  \begin{scope}[reg/.style={rectangle, shade,
      upper left=gray!30,
      draw=black,
      ultra thin,
      minimum width=1cm,
      minimum height=0.5cm}]
    \node [matrix]  at (9,0)
    {
      
      \node {$R_0$} ;&
            \node[reg] at (0,0) {} ;&
      \node[reg] at (0,0) {} ;&
      \node[reg] at (0,0) {} ;&
      \node[reg] at (0,0) {} ;& \\

      \node {$R_1$} ;&
         \node[reg] at (0,0) {} ;&
      \node[reg] at (0,0) {} ;&
      \node[reg] at (0,0) {} ;&
      \node[reg] at (0,0) {} ;& \\
    };
  \end{scope}
  
 %-------
 % ALU
 %-------
 \node[one bit adder,draw,scale=1.5, fill=pink!35] at (14,0) {};
 \node[rotate =90,scale=1.2](alu) at (14.15,0) {\textsf ALU};

\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The anchors are described in the generic `muxdemux` shapes; the `one bit adder` is just a particular instance of them. I'll try to answer as soon as I get my hand on a computer... ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The section of the manual you are looking for is the one about `muxdemux` anchors (4.24.2 as of today):

[image]

(There are more...). Moreover, you probably need to suppress the external pins (given your example):

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{flowchart}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}% arrows is deprecated
\usetikzlibrary {matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}

    \node[draw, black, thick,
    minimum width =5cm ,
    minimum height=5cm, , fill=teal!15] (regbox) at (9,0) {};

    \node[black,scale=1.0] at (9,2.2) {\textsf{REGISTER SET}};

    \begin{scope}[reg/.style={rectangle, shade,
            upper left=gray!30,
            draw=black,
            ultra thin,
            minimum width=1cm,
        minimum height=0.5cm}]
        \node [matrix]  at (9,0)
        {

            \node {$R_0$} ;&
            \node[reg] at (0,0) {} ;&
            \node[reg] at (0,0) {} ;&
            \node[reg] at (0,0) {} ;&
            \node[reg] at (0,0) {} ;& \\

            \node {$R_1$} ;&
            \node[reg] at (0,0) {} ;&
            \node[reg] at (0,0) {} ;&
            \node[reg] at (0,0) {} ;&
            \node[reg] at (0,0) {} ;& \\
        };
    \end{scope}

    %-------
    % ALU
    %-------
    %% vvvv give a name to the alu shape node (you named the text...)
    \node[one bit adder,draw,scale=1.5, fill=pink!35,
    circuitikz/multipoles/external pins width=0](alu) at (14,0) {};
    \node[rotate =90,scale=1.2] at (14.15,0) {\textsf ALU};
    %% arrow style, probably better in the preamble
    \tikzset{red arrow/.style={very thick, -{Straight Barb[]}, red}}
    %% using the perpendicular coordinate system here
    \draw[ red arrow ] (alu.blpin 1 -| regbox.east) -- (alu.blpin 1);
    \draw[ red arrow ] (alu.blpin 2 -| regbox.east) -- (alu.blpin 2);
    \draw[ red arrow ] (alu.east) -- ++(1,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]